# Converting time to readable form in R (x-posted on Stats)

Tags: r

```
10/16/2011 9:33:32 AM
10/16/2011 9:54:45 PM
10/16/2011 14:58:23 PM
10/17/2011 9:08:32 AM
```

The above are a few rows from my G$time column. I wanted to convert them to readable form when I graphed Y over Time, so I tried

```
Time<-strptime(G$Time,format="%D  %H:$M:%S %r")
```

and then

```
Time<-strptime(G$Time,format="%m/%d/%y  %H:$M:%S %r")
```

but I'm coming away with NA NA NA NA when I type in "Time". Can anyone help or give me a link to a good resource? I've looked at http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/strptime.html, but I can't seem to figure out my problem.

ETA: Problem solved.. but for future self-reference, just want to note that the G$Time format I had logged in R didn't match up to the "Time" column that was in the excel sheet. So whereas in Excel I had a timestamp that looked like "10/16/2011 9:33:32 AM", typing in G$Time in R got me "10/16/2011 9:33" with the seconds and the %r cut off. I wonder if I accidentally did something that perpetuated this case. In any case, finally figured out the small details thanks to the responders below.

Comment: What does the title have to do with this question?

Comment: You also posted the same question on the Stats sister site. Crossposting is considered bad taste.

Comment: Noted! I'll delete the other post. The title was a mistake (I had the draft of a different question written up before, and I figured out the solution.) Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Actually, I'm going to leave the other post up because of DWin's response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
strptime("10/16/2011 9:08",format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

works for me. You need (1) `%Y` capitalized for four-digit year; (2) `%M`, not `$M` (is this a typo in your question?); (3) no seconds (`%S`) field if there isn't one in the data; (4) no AM/PM field (`%r`) if there isn't one in the data.

**edit**: with the new data above,

```
strptime("10/16/2011 9:08:21 PM",format="%m/%d/%Y %r")
strptime("10/16/2011 9:08:21 PM",format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p")
```

both work for me.

**Note**: the formats are definitely case-sensitive (e.g. `%y` vs `%Y` matters) and may be locale-sensitive as well. According to `?strptime`, `%D` expands to `%m/%d/%y`, which would (I think) fail because it's looking for a 2-digit year.

Comment: Thank you! :) Yeah, a lot of it was in the details. For some reason my timestamp format in Excel did not match up to what R regurgitated when I queried the same column, so I just had to be careful.

Answer (score 1):

On statsexchange I suggested it would be better posted here, and that she could choose either of

```
Time<-strptime(G$Time,format="&m/%d/%Y  %H:$M")  # or

Time<-strptime(G$Time,format=""&m/%d/%Y  %R")
```

And it turned out that she had 2 spaces between the date and time, which was why I used them above

Comment: Thanks for the crosspost. I just figured out why your solution didn't seem to be working for me at first... the G$Time that's logged in R for some reason didn't match up to the "Time" column that was in the excel sheet. So whereas in Excel I had a timestamp that looked like "10/16/2011 9:33:32 AM", typing in G$Time in R got me "10/16/2011 9:33". I wonder if I accidentally did something that perpetuated this case.